# Class forward declaration leads to incomplete type

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class Node;

class Edge {
    public:
    //Edge(Node originnode,Node targetnode,int weight):OriginNode(originnode),TargetNode(targetnode),Weight(weight){};
    //~Edge(){};
    //Node getOriginNode() const { return OriginNode;};
    //Node getTargetNode() const { return TargetNode;};
    int getWeight() const { return Weight;};
    Node OriginNode;
    Node TargetNode;
    int Weight;
};

class Node{
    public:
    std::string getName();
    std::vector<Edge> getEdges();
};
```

when I am trying to compile the compiler claims that `OriginNode` and `TargetNode` have incomplete type. I have already forward declare the Node. How can I fix that?

Comment: This will only compile if it's a pointer to Node or a reference to Node

Comment: In C++ you can not have two class definitions needing the definition of each other.

Comment: The compiler's claims are correct: `Node` is an incomplete type when you use if in the `Edge` class definition.

Comment: As the declaration `std::vector<Edge> getEdges();` doesn't require a complete type `std::vector<Edge>`, you can reverse the order of class definitions. Just make sure the definition of the member function `getEdges` is after the definition of the `Edge` class. (It doesn't make sense, though, as Luchian points out.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't without providing a full definition of `Node`. You can alternatively declare pointers as members: `Node* OriginNode`.

I'd suggest you re-think your design though - does an Edge really have a Node. As in - does it have ownership over it? Can't a `Node` be shared between multiple edges? Also, Does a `Node` really **contain** multiple edges?

Answer (score 0):

With boost::container you can change the order of the declarations because it support containers of incomplete types :

```
    class Edge;

class Node{
    public:
    std::string getName();
    boost::container::vector<Edge> getEdges();
};

class Edge {
    public:
    //Edge(Node originnode,Node targetnode,int weight):OriginNode(originnode),TargetNode(targetnode),Weight(weight){};
    //~Edge(){};
    //Node getOriginNode() const { return OriginNode;};
    //Node getTargetNode() const { return TargetNode;};
    int getWeight() const { return Weight;};
    Node OriginNode;
    Node TargetNode;
    int Weight;
};
```

By the way, why do you want to return a value of the Edge vector when you get them from the Node and why do you store the value of the OriginNode and TargetNode inside the edge, you can use references or pointers instead (maybe I'm wrong, I don't know all your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the order of declarations

```
class Edge;

class Node{
    public:
    std::string getName();
    std::vector<Edge> getEdges();
};

class Edge {
    public:
    //Edge(Node originnode,Node targetnode,int weight):OriginNode(originnode),TargetNode(targetnode),Weight(weight){};
    //~Edge(){};
    //Node getOriginNode() const { return OriginNode;};
    //Node getTargetNode() const { return TargetNode;};
    int getWeight() const { return Weight;};
    Node OriginNode;
    Node TargetNode;
    int Weight;
};
```

Nevertheless I consider that design of classes as very bad. Node is a primitive entity that should not contain a vector of Edge. Why should Node control the container?! The container is a more high -level generalization than Node. So it should be placed in a more high level compared with Node.